# Adding an existing table with no Key to an Entity Framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a legacy table that I need to add to my EDM via VS2012.
I have updated the model via the "update model from database" menu choice.
This throws the error that a key can not be inferred and adds the remarked out code to the SSDL. 
I have seen references to creating a compound key in the EDM file to allow the table to be added (read only, which is fine) but have not been able to get it to work.

It involved un-remarking the SSDL, adding a CSDL entry, and C-S Mapping.

But I still get errors when trying to run the app about the table in question not being in the Metadata.

Any suggestions or pointers? Adding a key to the actual table is not possible in this case.

TIA

Comment: Can you add a key just on the EF side of things?  How do you identify a unique record in the table?

Comment: Yea I can add a compound key or even a "fake" key if I am not writing or deleting records.

Comment: Found this article:
http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.in/2012/04/entity-framework-adding-datatable-with.html

Comment: Do as the article suggested and create a compound key.  Is there a reason that doesn't work?

Comment: I have no idea what I did differently but it now works correctly.